# One Hot Encoding for States using sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to perform hot encoding for states using sklearn hot encoder. Here's my pandas dataframe:

```
State
0   FL
1   CA
2   MD
3   NY
4   NY
5   NY
6   NY
```

I wrote:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

enc=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
enc.fit(data)
```

And here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-a0b336acd757> in <module>()
----> 1 enc.fit(data)

/anaconda/envs/env3_insight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in fit(self, X, y)
   1842         self
   1843         """
-> 1844         self.fit_transform(X)
   1845         return self
   1846 

/anaconda/envs/env3_insight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
   1900         """
   1901         return _transform_selected(X, self._fit_transform,
-> 1902                                    self.categorical_features, copy=True)
   1903 
   1904     def _transform(self, X):

/anaconda/envs/env3_insight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in _transform_selected(X, transform, selected, copy)
   1695     X : array or sparse matrix, shape=(n_samples, n_features_new)
   1696     """
-> 1697     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
   1698 
   1699     if isinstance(selected, six.string_types) and selected == "all":

/anaconda/envs/env3_insight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NY'
```

I don't understand. I thought the whole point of doing a hot encoding is to convert from categorial, often string, information to numerics... Why is it saying I can't convert string to float, then?

Comment: You need to use LabelEncoder first.

Comment: OneHotEncoder , as the [documentation suggests](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), only accepts numerical data. First assign your data some numerical values like 1 for 'FL', 2 for 'CA' and so on.. and then use OneHotEncoding on them. For converting strings to numerical use LabelEncoder as suggested by @ayhan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas data frame have a build-in option to create one hot encoding, using [get_dummies method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html).

in your example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(['FL','CA','MD','NY','NY','NY','NY'], columns= ['State'])

pd.get_dummies(data.State)
```

will result in:

> CA    FL  MD  NY
>
> 0 0   1   0   0
>
> 1 1   0   0   0
>
> 2 0   0   1   0
>
> 3 0   0   0   1
>
> 4 0   0   0   1
>
> 5 0   0   0   1
>
> 6 0   0   0   1